# Animating CollectionViewSource

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, collectionviewsource

I am displaying a list of items using `CollectionViewSource` inside a `Grid` and was wondering if there is a way for an animation to occur when there is a change in what is being displayed by the `CollectionViewSource`?

I was thinking of something like a slide right or slide left animation.